# Influxdb over SSL connection

Tags: ssl, https, influxdb, lets-encrypt

I'm a little bit confused about https communication with influxdb. I am running a 1.8 Influxdb instance on a virtual machine with a public IP. It is an Apache2 server but for now I am not willing to use it as a webserver to display web pages to clients. I want to use it as a database server for influxdb.

I obtained a valid certificate from Let's Encrypt, indeed the welcome page https://datavm.bo.cnr.it works properly over encrypted connection.
Then I followed all the instructions in the docs in order to enable https: I put the `fullchain.pem` file in `/etc/ssl` directory, I set the file permissions (not sure about the meaning of this step though), I edited influxdb.conf with `https-enabled = true` and set the path for `https-certificate` and `https-private.key` (`fullchain.pem` for both, is it right?). Then, `systemctl restart influxdb`. When I run `influxdb -ssl -host datavm.bo.cnr.it` I get the following:

```
Failed to connect to https://datavm.bo.cnr.it:8086: Get https://datavm.bo.cnr.it:8086/ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.
```

Any help in understanding what I am doing wrong is very appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out at least a part of the problem. It was a problem related to permissions on the *.pem files. This thing looks weird because if I tip the following, as documentation says, it does not connect.

`sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssl/<CA-certificate-file>`

`sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssl/<private-key-file>`

If, instead, I tip the second line with 644 all works perfectly. But this way I'm giving to anyone the permission to read the private key! I'm not able to figure out this point.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

If I put inside `/etc/ssl/` the symlinks that point to the .pem files that live inside /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname the connection is refused. Only if I put a copy of the files the ssl connection starts.

The reason I am willing to put the links inside /etc/ssl/ is the automatic renew of the certificates.

Anyone can help?